# "Cannot redeclare class" issue in FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

Working namespaces in a default FuelPHP installation I add the following to the welcome controller (otherwise unedited) and I start getting the error:

```
ErrorException [ Compile Error ]: Cannot redeclare class Fuel\Controller\Welcome"
```

The code I is:

```
<?php

namespace Fuel\Controller;

use Fuel\Core\Controller;


class Welcome extends Controller
{
...
}
```

This is probably a beginner's question but I just can't figure out why the collision is occurring and I have tried everything I can think of.

EDIT:
I even tried putting the following code in front of the class and the error disappeared but a very generic looking 404 page was displayed. (Not the one that is displayed by default with FuelPHP but a black/grey one)

```
if (class_exists("Controller\Welcome",false)) {
//    echo "here. (" . __FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__ . ")\n";

} else {
    //Class definition...

}
```

Comment: May be `Welcome` class is already declared.

Comment: It's the default install, I have only changed the namespace and the use. That's it. I tried changing "welcome" to "welcomeABC" and got the same error: "ErrorException [ Compile Error ]: Cannot redeclare class Fuel\Controller\WelcomeABC"

Comment: having a namespace called controller, while at the same time using a class called Controller is a bit iffy IMO... best write `use Fuel\Core\Controller as CoreController;`

Comment: Elias Van Ootegem > A reasonable precaution. I tried implementing it now but got no change in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that you have to change the controller prefix in the config file to the following:

```
  'controller_prefix' => 'Controller\\',
```

Which is actually written in the documentation. (silly me)

Answer (score 0):

If your application has `multiple classes` with the same name `Welcome`, then it will give `error`

In `one file`

```
class Welcome extends Controller
{
   ...
}
```

In `another file`

```
class Welcome extends Controller
{
  ...
}
```

Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Cannot redeclare class Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511725/codeigniter-cannot-redeclare-class-hierarchy). 
See this [PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708140/php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class)

Comment: As I said above, I have not created multiple controllers called Welcome. This is a DEFAULT INSTALL of FuelPHP with only 2 lines changed (to add the namespace). Changing the name yields the same result so it is some issue with this file being read in twice by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers, you dont need set the namespace. The app know the default namespace.

if you remove the `namespace Fuel\Controller;` this error will disappear.